# do assembly codes trying to reach same register, damage anything when in different threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, inline-assembly

Is it dangerous to use __asm{} codes in threads?

For example, i have 2 threads running on a single core and main() on another core. What happens if one thread writes on eax and reads ebx while the other reads eax and writes on ebx? What happens if i read these register from main() ?

Comment: You understand that absolutely all the code your cpu runs is machine code, right? Whether you use `asm` or a high-level interpreted language doesn't change a thing.

Comment: you are right. i thought compiler changes names of registers but i dont know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each thread has its own set of registers that it maintains.  Either because it is running on a different core, or the operating system swaps out the registers on a context switch.

Answer (score 2):

Only your "global" (non-stack) variables are shared between threads.

This has been **[discussed already on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410778/how-does-a-computer-use-just-a-few-registers)**.